# ValueError: I/O operation on closed file Returned when adding a result to a txt document

Tags: list, python-3.x, index-error

Here Is a code I have made, More about it is explained below.

```
import os.path
if os.path.isfile('Times.txt'):        #checks if Times file exists
    file = open('Times.txt','r+')      #Opens file to read if it does
    with open('Times.txt','r+') as f:
        mylist = f.read().splitlines()
        mylist=[int(x) for x in mylist]
        mylist.sort()
        if sum(mylist)!=0:
            print('Highscore:',mylist[-1],'seconds')

else:
    file = open('Times.txt','w')        #Creates file if Times.txt does not exist
print("Type the alphabet as fast as you can!") #Game code- User types the alphabet as fast as they can.
time.sleep(1)
print("3")
time.sleep(1)
print("2")
time.sleep(1)
print("1")
time.sleep(1)
print("GO!!")
start = time.time()
alph=""
while alph != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
    alph=input("")
    if alph != "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
        print("INCORRECT ALPHABET, TRY AGAIN!")
end = time.time()
timetaken=(end - start)//1
Seconds=timetaken
mins=0
while timetaken >= 60:
    timetaken=timetaken-60
    mins=mins+1
Time = (mins,"minutes and",timetaken,"seconds") 
print('You took',Time)
f.write(str(Seconds)) #Adds time to text file
```

When I run the code, It returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Users\johnson.427\Desktop\Adam - Copy\Documents\Adam Homework\SWCHS\YEAR 9\Computing\challenge.py", line 104, in <module>
c7()
File "C:\Users\johnson.427\Desktop\Adam - Copy\Documents\Adam Homework\SWCHS\YEAR 9\Computing\challenge.py", line 102, in c7
f.write(str(Seconds))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

This is a code that I made, the task is to:
**Algorithm**
    Tell them to hit enter key when ready
    Get the first time in seconds (and minutes)
    Get them to type in the alphabet and hit enter
    Get the second time  in seconds (and minutes)
    Check they have entered the alphabet correctly
    If they entered it correctly then
       Subtract first time from the second time
       Tell them how many seconds they took
**Extension**
Keep a record of the best time achieved.         <------ *This is where I am stuck*
Deal with upper or lower case letters entered <------ *I can do this, I just didn't include it yet*

Edit: Is there another way to do this without using a txt document?

Comment: I think it may be because if you do it for the first time, there will be no items in the list, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Also, can anyone else notify me about any other **glaring** mistakes that will stop the code from functioning properly?

Comment: Add a default highscore of a really high time. This should prevent there being nothing in the file

Comment: Also when you write, you need to add a \n or it won't go to the next line

Comment: `f.write("\n+"Seconds)`

Comment: I fixed it, but it now returns the error above

Comment: the error means you are trying to write to a file that you haven't opened for writing yet; you need to `open` the file before writing to it: `with open('Times.txt','wb') as f: f.write(str(Seconds)) #Adds time to text file`

Answer (score 0):

My, my, what a mess of a code (no offense)... Your main/current problem is that you're opening the file within a `with` block so it closes the file handle as soon as you exit that `with` block - when you attempt to write to a closed file handle in the end you end up with the presented error.

First of all, there is no need to keep a file handle open to your highscore file, anyway - it's sufficient to open and read it when you start the 'game' and open and write to it when you want to save the score. So all this can be greatly simplified as:

```
import os.path
import time

hiscore = 0  # define our hiscore as 0 in case we want to use it somewhere else
if os.path.isfile('Times.txt'):  # checks if Times.exe file exists
    with open("Times.txt", "r") as f:  # open the file for reading
        hiscore = int(f.readline().strip())  # read the first line, we'll keep it sorted
        print('Highscore: {} seconds'.format(hiscore))

print("Type the alphabet as fast as you can!")
for line in ("3", "2", "1", "GO!!"):  # we can iterate-print instead of typing everything...
    time.sleep(1)
    print(line)

start = time.time()  # keep in mind that on Windows time.clock() is more precise!
while True:
    if input("") == "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":  # on Python 2.x use raw_input instead
        break
    print("INCORRECT ALPHABET, TRY AGAIN!")
end = time.time()

delta_time = int(end - start)
minutes, seconds = delta_time // 60, delta_time % 60
print("You took {} minutes and {} seconds".format(minutes, seconds))
# and now finally write the delta_time to the Times.txt
with open("Times.txt", "a+") as f:  # open Times.txt in read/write mode
    scores = {int(line.strip()) for line in f}  # read all the lines and convert them to ints
    scores.add(delta_time)  # add our current score
    f.seek(0)  # move to the beginning of the file
    f.truncate()  # truncate the rest
    f.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in sorted(scores)))  # write the sorted hiscores
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python

Comment: i'm in 3.5.2 if that helps

Comment: @AJ123 - Are you trying to edit the file by hand? If the first line in the `Times.txt` file is not a number (i.e. a blank line in your case) it will fail. The above code doesn't produce any blank lines but if you add them manually anything goes.